# Set destination Folder after create a sheet from a template

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The following script allow to create a spreadsheet from a another template spreadsheet selecting a specific row. 
But it create the sheet on my personal drive.
And so, how to set a **destination folder** by id?

**The Script:**

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Genera Scheda')
  .addItem('Genera Scheda', 'createSpreadsheet')
  .addToUi()}

function createSpreadsheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  // the following line means that the function will search for the spreadsheet name in the active sheet, no matter which one it is
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  //the selected row
  var row = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
  // column 2 corresponds to "B"
  var name = sheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue();
  var templateSheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('xxx');
  var templateSheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('xxx2');
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(name);
  templateSheet1.copyTo(newSpreadsheet).setName("Scheda");
  templateSheet2.copyTo(newSpreadsheet).setName("Import")
  newSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Foglio1"));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### To modify the destinaton folder with `DriveApp` use the methods [`addFile()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#addfilechild) and [`removeFile()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#removefilechild)

For this, the easiest is if you specify the `id` of the destination folder.

To move the file from the drive root folder to the specified folder based on your code you can add the following lines:

```
  var fileId = newSpreadsheet.getId();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  var folderId ="XXX";
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  folder.addFile(file);
  DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(file);
```

Comment: how to paste in cell B2 of the new tab "Scheda" the value in col G of the row selected in the template spreadsheet?